# Cannot start MySQL in XAMPP (Error:10048). Started Apache

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am new to XAMPP and I have got this error while trying to start MySQL. Help please :)

````
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 300333; transaction id 170
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210205 17:26:25
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-02-05 17:26:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to install xampp in administrator mode in windows and check the version windows 64 /32 bit.